# python anaconda requests.get(url) is working for http but not for https, getting ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: https

I am running the following code, in which url is http, while url1 is https.

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
currstatus=pd.DataFrame(data)

r = requests.get(url1)
data1 = r.json()
tms=pd.DataFrame(data1["Response"])
```

My http is getting the data but I am getting the following error while trying to get data from https url.

```
File "C:\Users\MUJEEB UR REHMAN\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\requests\adapters.py", line 502, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host name', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: [some credentials] (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect 
to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x000002B98468AB38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno  
11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))
```